# search for word or phrase in array element and return results using .filter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter an array by a user defined word so that it acts like a search. This might not be the way to go about it but I've never created a search before and it semms logical and fast. I have a an array 'dataset' containing my data in various object. it looks like this:
dataset [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Each object contains the following:

```
commenturl: "http://blogs.ft.com/businessblog/2013/12/"
definition: "To fire someone."
sourceurl: null
submisiondate: "02/11/2015"
usagesource: "HSBC"
phrase: "Transition out of the company"
wordid: "word001"
wordtype: "Verb"
```

I have an input form that when its changed returns its value to the variable 'lookup'. So if I type the word 'company' into the form then lookup='company'

I would then like to filter my dataset of objects on the element called 'phrase' to another array called 'results'. In the example above the element phrase='Transition out of the company' and as it contains the word 'company' which is the same as 'lookup' it should return the whole object to the results array.

In the second object of the array dataset the eleement phrase='Demise' so I would not expect this to be returned

Trying to do something like this but doesn't seem to work. Any help appreciated

```
var lookup=String(this.value)
        console.log("search",lookup);
        var results=dataset.filter(function(el){return el.word.text.indexOf(lookup) > -1)});
        console.log("results",results);
```

Comment: What you've posted is fine.  Can you post an example dataset?

Comment: 0: Object
commenturl: "http://blogs.ft.com/businessblog/2013/12/golden-flannel-awards-2013/"
definition: "To fire someone."
lucycommentary: "Used by HSBC in April [year?], when it took an axe to its corporate structure. The crassness got a lot of coverage at the time."
sourceurl: null
submisiondate: "02/11/2015"
usageexample: "“This integration of advisers means the roles of commercial financial advisers will be demised. ”"
usagesource: "HSBC"
word: "Demise"
wordid: "word001"
wordtype: "Verb"

Comment: Remove `.text` from the filter.  `word` is a string and strings do not have a `text` property.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. typed in the phrase 'company' expecting it to find the string of 'Transition out of the company" but reults remains empty. If I type the words 'demise' it returns that as its just the one word. Seems to not work when there is a sentence

Comment: Can you modify the question to include a data object and specify how you want to be able to search?  At the moment it's unclear as you've posted an example that tries to search the property `word`, but now you're saying it needs to also search something that you've not even shown us.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. changed a couple of names and amended post so hopefully this should now be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be an unmatched bracket, this now works

```
var lookup=String(this.value)
        console.log("search",lookup);
        var results=dataset.filter(function(el){
            return (el.word.indexOf(lookup) > -1)
        });
        console.log("results",results);
```